# Why is RestSharp posting form name/value pairs instead of JSON?

Tags: rest, restsharp

Why is RestSharp posting form name/value pairs instead of JSON when I have this line:  `request.RequestFormat = DataFormat.Json;

```
var request = new RestRequest($"api/Users/{userId}/UpdateProperty", Method.PUT);
request.RequestFormat = DataFormat.Json;
request.AddObject(new { key = key, value = value });
Execute(request);
```

This results in the following http request (checked using Fiddler):

```
PUT /api/Users/c8c946f9-e1dd-49c6-9c7f-23572017058a/UpdateProperty HTTP/1.1
Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded
Content-Length: 23
Accept-Encoding: gzip, deflate

key=Gender&value=Female
```

I was expecting the body to be JSON:

`{ 
    key: "Gender",
    value: "Female"
}`

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 0):

Instead of the AddObject method, you want to use the AddJsonBody method. You probably also want to add the "Content-type" header with "application/json" value.

Basically something like this:

```
var request = new RestRequest($"api/Users/{userId}/UpdateProperty", Method.PUT);
request.AddHeader("Content-type", "application/json");
request.RequestFormat = DataFormat.Json;
request.AddJsonBody(new { key = key, value = value });
Execute(request);
```